# Link to AIR application

Tags: air, adobe

I developed an Adobe AIR desktop application on macOS.
I want to make it available to all those who visit my blog. How can I make my Adobe AIR application available to all with a link on my blog?

Comment: It depends on your blog platform. Either it can handle binary files, or not. What is the URL of your blog?

Comment: boscarol.com/blog

Answer (score 1):

You air application must have been packaged in a file named like `my-app.air`. You have certainly built this file using an IDE like FlashBuilder, or a command line based on adt (something like `adt -package -target air .../my-app.air ...`).

Your blog is based on Wordpress. So, you may publish this `.air` file somewhere in your blog and post an article giving the URL.
If you can not do that, you may choose to store your `.air` file in one free upload server on the Internet. For instance, you may use http://mega.nz or http://dropbox.com, both have free plans that allow you to share files on a public URL that people can later download.

finally, you need to add an article on your blog that:

- ask people to download and install the AIR runtime from https://get.adobe.com/fr/air/
- and give the download URL of your `.air` file, provided by Mega, Dropbox or directly by Wordpress, depending on which service the file has been uploaded.